# Given the period of a trigonometric function, find the period of the transformed function

Tags: trigonometry

I would like someone to help me verify this exercise:

If the fundamental period of a periodic function $f$ is $4$, indicate the fundamental period of $3f(4x)+5$.

This is what I did:

$$Period=\frac{2\pi}{w_1}$$

$$4=\frac{2\pi}{w_1}$$

$$4w_1=2\pi$$

$$w_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Then, let's say: $f(x)=sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$

$$3f(4x)+5=3sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(4x))+5=3sin(2\pi x)+5$$

Then, the new period is:

$$Period=\frac{2\pi}{w_2}=\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}=1$$

Comment: Yes, logic seems fine. You have dropped the + 5 in your penultimate displayed equations, however, not that it affects the period. Also, I would use $\omega'$ second time around to distinguish this $\omega$ from the earlier one.

Comment: hahah i forgot! i already edited. thanks!! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have approached the problem differently.

The +5 term is irrelevant, because that is simply shifting the graph.

Similarly, the coefficient of 3 is irrelevant because that is merely stretching the graph.

Further, there is absolutely no reason to compare the function to trig functions, despite the fact that the original source of the function was a trig function.  Therefore, the factor of $\pi$ need not enter the discussion.

The two critical points are

- period of $f$ is 4.
- the new function [call it $g(x)$] relates to $f(4x)$.

Therefore, for example, since $f(4) = f(8)$, $g(1) = g(2).$

Therefore, it is immediate without math that the period of your function $3f(4x) + 5$ must be 1.